# HttpClient Set Content-Transfer-Encoding Header

Tags: c#, httpclient

a REST-API I want to use requires the header 'Content-Transfer-Encoding' to be set on each part of a multi-part-form-data-content.

I haven't found an option to set this header. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/5_Content-Transfer-Encoding.html shows the common values of: "BASE64" / "QUOTED-PRINTABLE" / "8BIT"   / "7BIT" / "BINARY" / x-token

which in C# can be set as per:

```
var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TransferEncoding.Add(new TransferCodingHeaderValue("BASE64"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just add any custom header you like to an HttpContentHeaders instance using [Add(string,string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158900(v=vs.118).aspx).

E.g.

```
string upload_file_path = @"C:\file_to_upload.bin";
var stream_content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(upload_file_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
stream_content.Headers.Add("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
```